# How to infer correct type when returning `payload is T` in typescript?

Tags: typescript, casting, type-inference, typeguards

I have a type guard check function that does tells JavaScript that a value is a promise or not, and at the same time it tells TypeScript that the variable is a promise:

```
function getType (payload: any): string {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(payload).slice(8, -1)
}    

function isPromise (payload: any): payload is Promise<any> {
  return getType(payload) === 'Promise'
}
```

It works really well, however, I realised I need to not hard code the promise resolve to `any` but infer that type instead.

This one example why I saw that `any` doesn't work properly:

```
export type PlainObject = { [key: string]: any }
let a: PlainObject | PlainObject[] | Promise<PlainObject | PlainObject[]>
let b = isPromise(a) ? await a : a
```

In this example, `b` is inferred as `PlainObject` while it SHOULD be `PlainObject | PlainObject[]`....

**Question 1:** Why is this happening?

My attempted solution at a better `isPromise` function:

```
type Unpacked<T> =
    T extends (infer U)[] ? U :
    T extends (...args: any[]) => infer U ? U :
    T extends Promise<infer U> ? U :
    T;

function isPromise2 <T extends any>(payload: T): payload is Promise<Unpacked<T>> {
  return getType(payload) === 'Promise'
}
```

In theory I don't see why this wouldn't work. But I get this error:

> A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
>     Type 'Promise>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>       'Promise>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any'

**Question 2:** Why doesn't `payload is Promise<Unpacked<T>>` work and 
how could I infer this otherwise?

Here is everything above in the TypeScript PlayGround:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#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-UGXURY0OkyFIrFEums1oMoWSzUGm0KFzXSdO32yJOZyAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: Why is this happening?

`PlainObject[]` is a *subtype* of `PlainObject`. In set theory, when you have  a union `Subtype | Supertype`, then the resulting type will be `Supertype` - it [absorbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#Some_additional_laws_for_unions_and_intersections) `Subtype`. So `b` gets type `PlainObject`  here.

Why is `PlainObject[]` a subtype? It gets clearer, when we look at  `Array` and `PlainObject` types:

```
interface Array<T> { [n: number]: T} // T is PlainObject for PlainObject[]
type PlainObject = { [key: string]: any }
```

In JS, `number` property key will become `string`. And no matter what `T` is, it  is assignable to `any`.

```
type PlainObjArr_extends_PlainObj  = PlainObject[] extends PlainObject ? true : false // true
```

> 2: Why doesn't payload is Promise> work and how could I infer this otherwise?

For custom type guards, the [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) (`is xxx`) must be a *subtype* of the checked argument. TS cannot verify here, that `Promise<Unpacked<T>>` is a subtype of `T`. Neglecting that fact, `isPromise` *does* its job filtering out all incompatible values of `a`:

```
let b = isPromise(a) ? await a /*Promise<PObj | PObj[]>*/ : a /*PObj | PObj[]*/
```

`any` - as often - is the evil one :o). A [solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=70&pln=11&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCoE8AOqAUOAhlgDZxEAmAXIkWFgJS0DOUATjGMogN4BQiRO3Qh2SAPIAjAFapoAOhzs4UVblQK1AZQ5dkCiEVKlCJclUYKWpGBAIAOADSIAtAEZG-AL79%20oSFgERBgWAAUVAFtQgmIyCho6BmZEOItKEJZECLhollQAHnosAD4%20QWFRcRR0bDwzeMtEAF5WxAByHLzUdp8-SnlSIhFEUnQ6WjChrmk5aEQAH2zpsFn5KABtAF1F7KiYgqmiGdl13aOTuc2tkr9UAA8cOHYoRCgNZePV0-nmvkQNgBrVBYVh6bhbWjgQFgOAAdyQvjGrykLUyXRi%20CIjEQAH46HDjq8iIhaCTEAB6CmIKSTFZreZLC7fK7bIA) is to make `PlainObject[]` incompatible to `PlainObject`:

```
export type PlainObject = { [key: string]: unknown } // e.g. replace `any` by `unknown`
let b = isPromise(a) ? await a : a  // b: PlainObject | PlainObject[]
```